# Running operation on background context in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, background

In an Android project, written in Kotlin, I have a data structure I want to perform some operations on on a single thread, because neither is designed to be thread safe, and the order of operations performed on it is important. I don't want that thread to be the main thread, because the operations are slow.

I've tried creating my threadContext multiple ways:

```kotlin
val threadContext = newFixedThreadPoolContext(1, "Background")
val threadContext = newSingleThreadContext("BioStackContext")
val threadContext = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

and every time, when I call run on it, I get isCurrent == true:

```kotlin
threadContext.run {
    val isCurrent = Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread()
```

However, if I call runBlocking on it, I get isCurrent == false:

```kotlin
runBlocking(threadContext) {
    val isCurrent = Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread()
```

How can I run it non-blocking in the background?

Comment: Why not coroutines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run` function you are calling is the Kotlin [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html), which has nothing to do with coroutines. It's a function that can be called on anything to create a lambda with it as the receiver, and the code is inline so it is run immediately on the current thread.

To use your dispatcher properly, you need a CoroutineScope that you use to `launch` a coroutine, and in that coroutine, you can use `withContext(threadContext)` to do your background work. On Android you should rarely need to create your own CoroutineScope, since Activities, Fragments, and ViewModels all provide you with one that is already scoped to their lifecycles.

If you were doing this task in an Activity or Fragment, it would look like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val result = withContext(threadContext) { // we are in the single thread context in this block
        calculateSomethingTimeConsumingWithObjectOnlyWorkedWithOnMySingleThreadContext()
    }
    // Back on main thread:
    updateUI(result)
}
```

In a ViewModel, you'd use `viewModelScope` instead of `lifecycleScope`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation :-)